# How To Add A Plus For My Tabs System In PyQt5 In Python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, pyqt5

So, basically I've been working on this web browser in PyQt5 in Python, and recently I found a tabs system, I've tweaked it, and I think it looks pretty nice!  But, there is an issue, to be able to open a tab I need to double click, and I can only open around 6 or 7.  These are obviously setbacks and I just can't seem to get either to work.  Anyways, in this post I would like to know hoe to add a plus sign to add a new tab (like in almost all modern web browsers).  I have been trying to play around with a button that has a plus sign on it in front of the newest tab, but it never seemed to work well.  I hope someone can help me!

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import os
import sys

print("Browser.")

print("\nBy:  ViridianTelamon.")

#Main window.
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    #Constructor.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Thing.png"))
        self.showMaximized()
 
        #Creating a tab widget.
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
 
        #Making document mode true.
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
 
        #Adding action when double clicked
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
 
        #Adding action when tab is changed.
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.current_tab_changed)
 
        #Making tabs closeable.
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
 
        #Adding action when tab close is requested.
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)
 
        #Making tabs as central widget.
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
 
        #Creating a status bar.
        self.status = QStatusBar()
 
        #Setting status bar to the main window.
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)
 
        #Creating a tool bar for navigation.
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
 
        #Adding tool bar tot he main window.
        self.addToolBar(navtb)
 
        #Creating back action.
        back_btn = QAction("", self)
        #Setting status tip.
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Go Back To Previous Page.")
        #Adding action to back button.
        #Making current tab go back.
        back_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().back())
        #Adding this to the navigation tool bar.
        navtb.addAction(back_btn)
 
        #Similarly adding forward button.
        next_btn = QAction("", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Go Forward To Next Page.")
        next_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().forward())
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)

        #Url view button.
        #url_view = QAction("Url View", self)
        #url_view.setStatusTip(webEngineView.url().toString())
        #url_view.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().forward())
        #navtb.addAction(url_view)
 
        #Similarly adding reload button.
        reload_btn = QAction("", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload The Page.")
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().reload())
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)
 
        #Creating home action.
        home_btn = QAction("", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go To The Home Page.")
 
        #Adding action to home button.
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)

        #Adding a separator.
        navtb.addSeparator()
 
        #Creating a line edit widget for URL.
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
 
        #Adding action to line edit when enter key is pressed.
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
 
        #Adding line edit to tool bar.
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)

        #Similarly adding stop action.
        stop_btn = QAction("", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop Loading The Current Page.")
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().stop())
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)
 
        #Creating first tab.
        self.add_new_tab(QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/"), "Homepage")
 
        #Showing all the components.
        self.show()
 
        #Setting window title.
        self.setWindowTitle("Browser")
 
    #Method for adding new tab.
    def add_new_tab(self, qurl = None, label ="Blank"):
 
        #If url is blank.
        if qurl is None:
            #Creating a url to be the default one.
            qurl = QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/")
 
        #Creating a QWebEngineView object.
        browser = QWebEngineView()
 
        #Setting url to browser.
        browser.setUrl(qurl)
 
        #Setting tab index.
        i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)
 
        #Adding action to the browser when url is changed.
        #Update the url
        browser.urlChanged.connect(lambda qurl, browser = browser:
                                   self.update_urlbar(qurl, browser))

        #Adding action to the browser when loading is finished.
        #Set the tab title.
        browser.loadFinished.connect(lambda _, i = i, browser = browser:
                                     self.tabs.setTabText(i, browser.page().title()))
 
    #When double clicked is pressed on tabs.
    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, i):
 
        #Checking index.
        #No tab under the click.
        if i == -1:
            #Creating a new tab.
            self.add_new_tab()
    
    #Adding a new tab.
    #def add_new_tab(self, qurl=None, label="Blank"):
        #if qurl is None:
            #qurl = (self.tabs.currentWidget()).url()
            #qurl = QUrl('https://www.duckduckgo.com/')
        #browser = QWebEngineView()

        #browser.loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
        #browser.loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinishedHandler)

        #i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)
        #self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)

        #browser.load(qurl)
 
    #When tab is changed.
    def current_tab_changed(self, i):
 
        #Get the current url.
        qurl = self.tabs.currentWidget().url()
 
        #Update that url.
        self.update_urlbar(qurl, self.tabs.currentWidget())
 
        #Update that title.
        self.update_title(self.tabs.currentWidget())
 
    #If the tab is closed.
    def close_current_tab(self, i):
 
        #If there is only one tab as well.
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            #Do nothing.
            return
        page = self.tabs.widget(i)
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)
        page.deleteLater()
 
        #Otherwise remove the tab.
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)
 
    #Method for updating the title.
    def update_title(self, browser):
 
        #If signal is not from the current tab.
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():
            #Then do nothing.
            return
 
        #Get the page title.
        title = self.tabs.currentWidget().page().title()
 
        #Set the window title.
        self.setWindowTitle("% s  |  Browser" % title)
 
    #Action to go to home.
    def navigate_home(self):

        #Go to home page.
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/"))
 
    #Method for navigate to url.
    def navigate_to_url(self):
 
        #Get the line edit text.
        #Convert it to QUrl object.
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
 
        #If the scheme is blank.
        if q.scheme() == "":
            #Set a scheme.
            qurl = (self.tabs.currentWidget()).url()
            q.setScheme("https")
 
        #Then set the url.
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(q)
 
    #Method to update the url.
    def update_urlbar(self, q, browser = None):
 
        #If this signal is not from the current tab then ignore it.
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():
 
            return
 
        #Set text to the url bar.
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())
 
        #Set cursor position.
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)
 
#Creating a PyQt5 application.
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
#Setting name to the application.
app.setApplicationName("Browser.")
 
#Creating MainWindow object.
window = MainWindow()
 
#Main Loop.
app.exec_()
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71624309/2001654), even if it's not directly related to the question, it already implements it.

Comment: This may help me, so thank you.  But, where in the code would I put this.

Comment: Study the code of that answer and try to understand what are the parts related to the add button.

Comment: Okay, will do, thank you for the help.  But, one last thing (if you can).  There is a bug where if you close the second last tab then it closes the last and second last tab.  I think you would have to keep track of the tabs and their numbers but I don't know for sure, how would you fix this.

Comment: In that answer I have not implemented the tab removal, the bug is in your code because you called `self.tabs.removeTab(i)` twice.

Comment: Oh thank you, it's fixed now.  One final thing, how could you make it so that the tabs shrink (without the plus in front, so not the post that you put above).  Also, where you do find all these answers, I can't find any (interms of websites and posts).

Comment: I don't understand your question: in that post the tab *do* shrink, that's exactly what the question was about. About finding "those answers", that's mostly experience (and in this specific case, coincidence, as I wrote that answer just a few days ago); I've been writing with PyQt and patiently studied Qt sources for *years*, so I know the right terms I need when I want to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: So it's experience then, I see that does make sense then.  Well thank you, however how come you posted your comment and a comment and not an answer?

Comment: On SO we try to avoid duplicate answers (even if they are about a different problem). Since that answer already solves your problem, I don't see the need to create a new one now, and I actually don't have time to create a well thought/written one at the moment. Please consider that Qt is as powerful as it has a tough and steep learning curve. It could take several months (or years) of profound and careful studying to master it: the more you learn, the more you find out that you still have to learn about it. Be patient, *always* read the documentation and as soon as possible study its sources.

Comment: Where is the documentation?

Comment: Here is the list of all [Qt classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/classes.html). I know it's intended for C++ programmers, but that's what you get, and it's the **only** reliable source of documentation. Note that 99.9% of the functions and arguments are named and behave exactly in the same way in PyQt. In case of doubt (especially for arguments and returned types), just call `help(class.function)` in the interactive python shell. It takes some time to get used with it, but it's worth it. As said, if you want to learn Qt, you have to be patient.